# What's the most efficient way to emplace a new element in a vector?

Tags: c++

If I want to add a new element to a vector there are a couple of ways I can do it:

```
struct ZeroInitialisedType
{
int a, b, c, d, e, f;
}

std::vector my_vector;

ZeroInitialisedType foo;
foo.a = 7;
//....
my_vector.push_back(foo);
```

1. Can the compiler make it so that instead of writing into the local variable and then copying it into the vector memory at the end() that it writes it directly into the vector memory?
2. Does the fact that the end() pointer may change (if the vector is resized) influence whether or not it can optimize two writes to one?
3. What's the most efficient way to add this element to the end of the vector and write values to it?

The last question has got me thinking a bit about modern C++'s annoying quirks about value initialization. For example:

```
my_vector.emplace_back(); // PUSH A NEW OBJECT AT THE END
ZeroInitialisedType& ref = my_vector.back();
ref.a = 7;
//....
```

The problem with the above is that it zero initialises the new object on emplace_back(), then I write into it again. The same problem goes with this:

```
my_vector.emplace_back(ZeroInitialisedType());
// or
my_vector.push_back(ZeroInitialisedType());
```

If the element type of the vector isn't zero initialized then I assume the most efficient way would be to emplace_back with zero arguments, get a reference and write into it. However, when it's zero-initialized that's not the case and it becomes a problem.

Also, I'm aware that a hack could be to add a user-defined constructor to the class type, but that's not good at all to avoid zero-initialization.

Comment: When you want that "it writes it directly into the vector memory" might not be possible, if there's no memory allocated for the vector, or if its capacity is equal to its size.

Comment: Also the name `ZeroInitialisedType` seems to be misleading if what you want is *no* initialization. And it's equally misleading if you want zero-initialization and define instances as local variables (where no initialization will happen).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do you mean it's misleading? That type is zero-initialised if value-initialised according to the rules. Locally I can decide to value-initialise it (hence zero-initialise it) depending on if I add braces ( ) or { }. I didn't know what else to call it, I think that's a good name. Do you mean it should be ZeroInitialisedIfValueInitialisedType?

Comment: Yes you *can* value initialize the structure, but in your example you *don't*. While this is a simple example, it's still misleading to use such a name when the actual zero initialization must be explicit and not part of the structure itself. IMO.

Comment: Some demo assembly: https://godbolt.org/z/zavvrTGj6. Note that the version with "empty" `emplace_back` is the only one that does not construct an object first on the stack. It even seems to be the most efficient. Yes, it zero-initializes the members `b` to `f`. But that do the other versions as well. BTW, even direct initialization seems to zero all the non-initialized members: https://godbolt.org/z/vW7M8Y5dh. It is prescribed by the aggregate-initialization rules. This may be avoided by adding a custom constructor, but the class will no longer be aggregate: https://godbolt.org/z/7jG4exbnh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two independent questions related to your problem. The first one is whether an object of type `ZeroInitialisedType` can be constructed such that some of its members are not zero-initialized. I believe this is not possible according to the *aggregate-initialization* rules. A simple demo is:

```
struct X { int a, b, c, d, e, f; };

void f(X* ptr)
{
    new (ptr) X{7};  // the same with X(7) and X{.a=7}
}
```

Here, all members `b` to `f` are zero-initialized in `f()`.

You can avoid this zeroing by adding the corresponding constructor; however, the class will no longer be an aggregate:

```
struct Y
{
    Y(int a_) : a(a_) { }
    int a, b, c, d, e, f; 
};

void f(Y* ptr)
{
    new (ptr) Y(7);
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/3aWooxWK7.

The second question is whether the object can be constructed directly in the vector's buffer. I tried some versions with libstdc++ and only the version with "empty" `emplace_back` plus the `back` call did that.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zavvrTGj6.

I guess the cause is in the possible reallocation, which is in our case accomplished by the `_M_realloc_insert` call. It seems that those calls with non-empty template argument require the source to be in memory (the address is then passed via `RDX`). Therefore, the addressed objects need to be first stored to the stack.

The version with empty `emplace_back` does not have such requirements and succeeded with the direct construction in the vector's buffer. Of course, this analysis is GCC+libstdc++-related only.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using following for inserting a small trivial aggregate type for readability:

```
my_vector.push_back({
    .a = 7,
});
```

However, emplacing may technically more efficient:

```
my_vector.emplace_back(7);
```